How to detect missed calls and busy status in Azure Communication Services?
I'm building an app using Azure Communication Services (ACS) where users can call each other. I'm using Event Grid to handle call events like CallStarted, CallEnded, etc. I need to implement the following logic:

Missed Call Detection: If a user A calls user B and user B doesn't answer, I need to mark it as a missed call.

In A Call Detection: If user A tries to call user B but user B is already on another call, I need to notify user A that user B is currently busy ("in a call").


I've set up an Event Grid subscription and can receive the events like CallStarted, CallEnded, and ParticipantAdded, IncomingCall, but I'm not sure how to correctly detect missed calls or when a user is already in a call.
Has anyone implemented something similar using ACS and Event Grid in 1:1 call? What event combinations or patterns should I look for to detect these states correctly?

Please share the code you tried in text format and the document you referred to
